# Function to push numbers to an array. If each number that's being pushed is increasing by one and also checking if the number % by 3, 5, 3 and 5 == 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Good day to you all. I'm new to JavaScript and while following an online course, I encountered a problem that I need to solve. Please bear in mind that I'll need answers to be as lay/explicit as you can.

The function is supposed to add number one to an empty array at first and, keep pushing other integers that's steadily increasing (++) by 1. Before pushing, it'll check if it's divisible without remainder by 3, 5, 3 and 5 and would return a string if it support the conditional.

I'm looking forward to the answers I'm hoping to get as I think my lack of basics of programming language is hindering me from solving this.

```js
function fizzBuzz() {
    let output = [1, 2, ]; // An empty array
    let num = 1; // The first num that'll be pushed to the array
    num = num++; // Increasing the value of the variable
    output.push(num); // Pushing the number to the array
    
    //Conditionals
    if (num++ % 3 === 0) {      
        return output.push("Fizz");
    } else if (num++ % 5 === 0) {           
        return output.push("Buzz");
    } else if (num++ % 3 === 0 && num++ % 5 === 0) {
        return output.push("FizzBuzz");
    } else {
        return output.push(num++);
    }
}
console.log(fizzBuzz());
```

This is what I've tried so far and it's even confusing me the more I think about it.

Comment: You need to check the 3 and 5 case **first**

Comment: What are the others saying? At every `if` the `num` is incremented. 

Comment: There is so much wrong in this code, that I think you better take a step back and solve a simpler problem, like a function that returns an array with a given number of asterisks. If you give it 5 it should return `["*","*","*","*","*"]`. Once you have that working, make a function that returns an array with numbers 1, 2, 3, ... up to the given value. So if you give it 5 it should return `[1,2,3,4,5]`. If you cannot make this work, don't start on the task you have posted about, and research how to do those things first.

Answer (score 0):

You should make yourself familiar with using a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems), that allows you to step through your code line by line. Then you will notice a few points:

1. how is `let output = [1, 2, ];` an "empty array"?
2. You don't have any loop, and everytime you call your function, you start over with `let num = 1`
3. `num = num++;` is quite a "dangerous" construct for a beginner to use and interpret (and sometimes also for experienced developers) and will most certainly not do what you expect it to do (ie `num` won't be changed after that line.) And in other C like languages, that might even be undefined behaviour.
4. You are incrementing your `num` in every `if`. Probably not what you want to do.
5. Consider `num` to be a value like `15` (not that it can ever reach that value with your code, but lets just imagine). So you should somehow arrive in your last `if`, but you never will, because you already `return` from your first `if`, because `num` is divisible by 3.
6. And finally, [`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) does not return the array, but just the length of the array after the new element was added. So probably, not what you expect. That's why your code is outputting `4` instead of an array ...

I won't give you working code, because that would (in my opinion) defeat the purpose of a the course. But if you take into account, the points I gave you above, you should be able to solve that assignment.

Comment: This I can say has been an answer I am expecting. I appreciate the simplicity. Will work on it.